trying to iterate over 1 dataframe and get values from another using .loc
I am new to Python and need to lookup data from df1 and add a column to df2 based on a column value and loop through all records in df2 until column "codekey1" is populated with the related data from df1.
I have seen this post and trying to replicate it:
Iterating over dataframe rows with for loop - problem with .loc
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "invoice":["Z1234","Z1234","Z10444","Z10444","Z56789","Z56789","Z34555","Z34555"],
    "amount":["10.10","10.10","11000.23","11000.23","567.34","567.34","4567.55","4567.55"],
    "codekey":["100","200","100","200","100","200","100","200"],
    "codevalue":["CO123","PO123","CO345","PO345","CO567","PO567","CO789","PO789"]
})

output df1:
df1
  invoice    amount codekey codevalue
0   Z1234     10.10     100     CO123
1   Z1234     10.10     200     PO123
2  Z10444  11000.23     100     CO345
3  Z10444  11000.23     200     PO345
4  Z56789    567.34     100     CO567
5  Z56789    567.34     200     PO567
6  Z34555   4567.55     100     CO789
7  Z34555   4567.55     200     PO789`

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "invoice":["Z1234","Z10444","Z56789","Z34555"],
    "amount":["10.10","11000.23","567.34","4567.55"],
    "codekey1":["","","",""],
    "codekey2":["","","",""]
})

required output:
`df2`
  invoice    amount codekey1 codekey2
0   Z1234     10.10    C0123
1  Z10444  11000.23    CO345
2  Z56789    567.34    CO567
3  Z34555   4567.55    CO789

I run this code:
for i in range(len(df2)):
    codekey_lookup = (df1.loc[(df1["invoice"] == df2.loc[i, "invoice"] & df2["codekey"] == "100"), "codevalue"]).to_list()[0]
    df2.loc[i, "codekey1"] = codekey_lookup

and get this error:
KeyError: 'codekey'

Hope someone can help..

Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. This is a Q&A site, but you haven't asked a question and it's not clear what you need help with. Please read [ask]. You can [edit] to clarify if needed.

Also, please post the full error message with traceback.

@wjandrea the full error with traceback is already there, no?

@Quang No, it's missing OP's code. They only copied the last 4 stack entries.

That's pretty sufficient as the code is super simple. The minimal reproducible data/sample is there.

Oh, is the problem just a typo? I mean, is df2["codekey"] meant to be df1["codekey"]? In that case, questions caused by typos aren't considered useful on Stack Overflow unless they have some substance. In the future, making a [mre], like restarting from scratch, can help catch basic mistakes like that.

@Quang Did you see my first two comments? There's no question here, the title and body don't really describe the problem (the error), and the "required output" is missing, so this is not a good question.

@Quang OK, yeah, the full traceback isn't really necessary, but it's good practice. I think I misread the code on my first readthrough which made the error not make sense to me.

@Quang I just realized the required output was there but in the wrong place. I fixed it.

The error says it, df2 doesn't have a codekey column. so in your code df2["codekey"] == "100" throws that error. Also, you need to wrap the equal op in parenthesis like this
for i in range(len(df2)):
    codekey_lookup = ((df1.loc[(df1["invoice"] == df2.loc[i, "invoice"]) 
                      & (df1["codekey"] == "100"), "codevalue"])
                     ).to_list()[0]
    df2.loc[i, "codekey1"] = codekey_lookup

On another note, you might want to take a look at merge or map operation rather than looping with loc. For example, the following does the same thing, just a lot faster:
code_by_invoice = df1.loc[df1['codekey']=='100', ['invoice','codevalue']].set_index('invoice')

df2['codekey1'] = df2['invoice'].map(code_by_invoice['codevalue'])

Output:
  invoice    amount codekey1 codekey2
0   Z1234     10.10    CO123         
1  Z10444  11000.23    CO345         
2  Z56789    567.34    CO567         
3  Z34555   4567.55    CO789         


Hi Quang, Thanks alot for the suggestions. . I do not fully understand how .loc works so made some mistakes that I did not realise due to this.  I tried this corrected code and it works great . Thanks alot !   I will replicate this on my actual df's which have multiple columns and also different data types , so will advise tomorrow.   I also need to do the same logic for the other column "codekey2" so will  duplicate the logic for that I think.  For .map / .merge I will test that also and if that is better will switch.

Hi wjandrea, thanks for your edits also and will try better next time I post !

@Gursi-ng if you're working to bring over more than one columns at the same time, then you should definitely look into merge. A good start can be this question

Ok will have a look at that post. Can .map be used also or is .join preferable ?

.join is usually used when you merge multiple dataframes. If you only merge with one other dataframe, it's works the same as .merge. .map is only used when you map the index to something else. That's why in my code, I have set_index('invoice').
